# Prevent Appium from launching application?

Tags: appium, nightwatch.js

I am testing canvas based web application and i have situation where i need to merge python UI automator based testing technique with Nightwatch's End to End  testing. Since canvas based android application doesn't have locator id for some parts i need to test those using nightwatch feature. Nightwatch uses Appium and sets desired configuration for launch. So situation is i have written few steps with UI Automator Python and next step i call node command from python subprocess which causes same application to relaunch.

1. I want to avoid Appium relaunch somehow. EDIT : I am able to achieve it by setting **autoLaunch** **False**
2. Mechanism to completely avoid Appium and direct send client API on mobile application launched on phone and get response.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve it by setting autoLaunch False